# Probability - failure analysis of more than one item

Tags: probability

Lets say you have an item that fails 2% when you turn it off and on 100 times.

Now lets say you have 4 of those items.  What is the likelihood that any 1 of the 4 items fails during another 100 on/off tests.  Assume all 4 of the unit turn off/on at the same time.  If it is easier to think of the items in series that would be the same thing.

Comment: is this 'exactly one' or 'one or more' fails

Comment: also, fails 'exactly once' or 'at least once'?

Comment: one or more fails.

Comment: which of the two? I mean, one or more devices or one device that fails one or more times?

Comment: My bad.  If any number of the 4 items fails then the "test" would be a failure.  So I think "at least one".

Answer (score 1):

Each device has the probability to fail, $0.02$, which means that the 'actual' probability of failure is $P_F = 1-0.98^{100}$, i.e. that the device fails at least once in the 'whole' experiment. Next thing you need is the probability that it happens to any of the $4$ devices which is of course $1$ - probability this doesn't happen to any of them. Can you handle from here?

Comment: Thank you Alex.  Its been about 8 years since I have worked with probabilities in college so I am beyond rusty.  I am at least headed in the right direction I think.

Comment: You are welcome. Are you studying for a GMAT exam or something?

Comment: Small DIY project I am playing around with.  Have some electronics that work correctly 98% of the time when I work with them independently.  When I put them in a group I see at least one of them fail about 8-10% of the time.  I was trying to see if this was something wrong with my project or if it was theoretically what I should expect to see.

Comment: OK good luck with your project.